# FIlter a dictionary array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, dictionary

I'm using a feth request to recieve data from an API.
This is what my request looks like:

```
fetch(url, requestOptions)
.then(response => response.json())
.catch(error => colsole.log('error', error);
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to filter certain values from the response.
Here's what the response looks like:

```
[
  {
    'Obj.Name': 'objname1',
    'Obj.property': 'red'
    ...
  },
  {
    'Obj.Name': 'objname1',
    'Obj.property': 'blue'
    ...
  },
  {
    'Obj.Name': 'objname3',
    'Obj.property': 'green'
    ...
  },
]
```

I wanna add another ".then" statement there with a function that gets a parameter like ('Obj.Name') that can filter everything by that particular objectname and be able to get other properties of that object.
I want the result to be something like this:

```
Obj: objectname1, ObjProp: red
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
fetch(url, requestOptions)
.then(response => response.json())
.then((data) => {
  const filtered = data.filter(item => item["Obj.Name"] === "objname1")
  console.log(filtered)
})
.catch(error => colsole.log('error', error);
```

Comment: Yep that worked! What about if I wanted to extract the 'Obj.property' key from that particular object? do I run the filter function again on the filtered object?

Comment: You can use method find. Like data.find(item => item["Obj.Name"] === "objname1")

Comment: One last question, what about filtering with multiple ["Obj.Name"] values. Like saving objects with the name "objectname1" and "objectname2".